# How to perform a query at the URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

If I want to show posts in travel category the URL is

> example.com/category/travel

If I want to show posts in 2007 the URL is

> example.com/2007

If I want to show posts in travel category published in 2007 the URL is

> example.com/2007/?category_name=travel

My questions are

1- Why URL

> example.com/category/travel/?year=2007

falls back to

> example.com/2007

and related question

2- Why such an URL (to show all posts in travel category published before 2007) does not work?

> example.com/category/travel/?year<=2007

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind this is how the URL rewriting works. No matter what is the setting of your permalink structure, all the requests will be redirected to `index.php`. So, for example:

```
example.com/category/travel
```

will eventually turn into:

```
example.com/index.php?cat=travel
```

So in your example:

```
example.com/category/travel/?year=2007
```

will be turned into:

```
example.com/index.php?cat=travel&year=2007
```

and possibly because the last argument overrides the first, the above will turn into this:

```
example.com/index.php?year=2007
```

Which will query the posts that are published in 2007.

### Why `year<=2007` doesn't work?

You can't pass comparison arguments in that way. The query argument must be equal to something, so queries like `year<2000` are not valid. You can pass it like `year=<2007`, but it is up to the script to honor your request. Some scripts might be programmed to recognize it, some not.

Right now, by sending `year<=2007`, you are telling the server that the value for `year<` is equal to `2007`.

Comment: @birgire Thanks for the edit but that one was intentional. I think if you use 2 query args in that way, they will not be formatted properly, and that might be why the query doesn't work at all.

Comment: This is simple and on point. Great answer.

Comment: ok sorry if that was intentional, but I'm not sure about double ?. The canonical redirect is responsible for the redirect of `example.com/category/travel/?year=2007`. i.e. the monster  `redirect_canonical()` function.

Comment: @birgire The reason is because I thought we can query posts from 2007 and `travel` category by sending the `index.php?cat=travel&year=2007`. Is it possible?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/e8229a25d5f4c620ef5f021abe70224cc6c550de/wp-includes/canonical.php#L203-L205) are the lines responsible for the redirect activation in `redirect_canonical()`. I guess it's possible to filter it out if needed, i.e. to remove the specific `get_year_link(get_query_var('year'))` redirect url.

Comment: @JackJohansson Thank you for the answer. I think I understood what you mean and what the problem is but I want to test it before I accept the answer. One side note "cat=travel" does not work it should be "category_name=travel"

Comment: @physicopath if we want to leave the canonical redirects as is, one can also introduce custom query variables to filter the main query on specific pages. For example the `date_query` of `WP_Query` supports the  `before`  parameter, if you are looking into a query for `<= 2017`.

Comment: @JackJohansson there is an error in the answer: the URL example.com/index.php?category_name=travel&year=2007 actually works. It does not turn into example.com/index.php?year=2007 but it turns to example.com/2007/?category_name=travel. Although as I stated in my question example.com/category/travel/?year=2007 turns to example.com/2007. Weird!

Comment: index.php?category_name=travel&year=2007&author_name=bob also works, the author_name does not overwrite the others

Comment: unfortunately I cannot sent an array either so this does not work either index.php?category_name=travel&year=2007,2006,2005